# How to import from both a python file in a folder and a file on the same directory being called?

Tags: python

Consider this example:

```
/project
|  main.py
|  database.py
L  /database
   L   users.py
```

There are variables in both database.py and users.py. users.py is in a folder called database within the project. Is it possible to import both database.py's variables and users.py variables from main.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import stuff from the `database` dir, you need to have an `__init__.py` file inside it, even if it's empty. `database` is then said to be a "package".

You can't have `database.py` and a `database` dir though, because doing `import database` will import the `__init__.py`, not `database.py`. So you can simply move everything from `database.py` in the `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more explicit about your use case?

You can import variables with the normal `import` statement.

```
from database import a, b
from lib.users import c, d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(a, b)
    print(c, d)
```

Note that there has to be a file called `__init__.py` in your sub-folder, e.g. `lib`, for imports to work.

However, importing from a folder and a file with the same name (`database`) leads to conflicts.
You have to rename one of the files for the import to be non-ambigous.